# Приложение вылетает при использовании SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, дата

В коде используется SimpleDateFormat для преобразования строки типа "2016-11-05" в строку вроде "05.11.2016". Проблема в том, что при использовании SimpleDateFormat эмулятор с API24 и API23 работает нормально, а с API22 и ниже вылетает с ошибкой:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: ru.example.test, PID: 2532
>                     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat;

Никак не могу понять, в чём проблема? Кто сталкивался, подскажите куда копать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До API24 используйте [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) вместо [android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).